# Casting a component through an interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a universal function for finding components that belong to a given interface in unity. I am able to do it when I specify the interface, but I need to be able to abstract it, any way I could do that?

The specified version

```
public static Component GetComponentOfTypeMovement(GameObject gameObject)
{
    foreach (var component in gameObject.GetComponents<Component>()) //Go through each component on this character.
    {
        try //Attept something, and if it fails, goto catch.
        {
            var n_component = (IMovement)component; //Cast the current component as IMovement, if successful movementComponent will be set, and we can break from this loop.
            return (Component)n_component; //Return the component if it has been found.
        }
        catch //If we have failed to do something, catch it here.
        {
            continue; //Simply keep checking the components, if we have reached this point, then the component we have attempted is not of type IMovement.
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The abstract version

```
public static Component GetComponentOfType<T>(GameObject gameObject)
{
    foreach (var component in gameObject.GetComponents<Component>()) //Go through each component on this character.
    {
        try //Attept something, and if it fails, goto catch.
        {
            var n_component = (T)component; //Cast the current component, if successful movementComponent will be set, and we can break from this loop.
            return (Component)n_component; //Return the component if it has been found.
        }
        catch //If we have failed to do something, catch it here.
        {
            continue; //Simply keep checking the components, if we have reached this point, then the component we have attempted is not of the specified type.
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Instead of try catch you could do `var result = component as T; if (result != null) return (Component) result;`, and you'd need a constraint on `T` to do the casting I believe: `where T : Component`

Comment: I tried adding a constraint, the problem with that is it won't take in an interface if it is constrained by component.

Comment: Ideal usage = GetComponentOfType<IMovement>(gameObject);

Comment: Does this work? `return gameObject.GetComponents<Component>().Where(c => c is T).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Or maybe this: `return gameObject.GetComponents<Component>().OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();`. Sorry, not at a computer right now.

Comment: Like a charm! Thanks so much! If you don't mind posting that as the answer that would be great! (return gameObject.GetComponents<Component>().Where(c => c is T).FirstOrDefault();)

Comment: Please be my guest and answer it yourself. I'll be away for a bit.

Comment: `GetComponent<IYourInterface>()` should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Rufus L! He provided the answer, being:

```
        public static Component GetComponentOfType<T>(GameObject gameObject)
        {
            return gameObject.GetComponents<Component>().Where(c => c is T).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Usage:

```
        private IMovement movementComponent
        {
            get //When we try to retrieve this value.
            {
                if (storedMovementComponent != null) //Check if this value has already been set.
                {
                    return storedMovementComponent; //If the component does exist, return it.
                }
                else
                {
                    return (IMovement)Utilities.GetComponentOfType<IMovement>(gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This does require the usage of System.Linq FYI

Comment: Removing the where works too
``` gameObject.GetComponents<Component>().FirstOrDefault(c => c is T); ```